# DataSource Router problem in multiples access of multiples datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have project spring-boot using datasource routes in three diferents datasources.

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new EnvironmentAwareCacheKeyGenerator();
    }

}
```

--

```
public class DatabaseContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<DatabaseEnvironment> CONTEXT =
        new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(DatabaseEnvironment databaseEnvironment) {
        CONTEXT.set(databaseEnvironment);
    }

    public static DatabaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
        return CONTEXT.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        CONTEXT.remove();
    }

}
```

--

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsuarioRepository.class, 
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "customerEntityManager", 
                       transactionManagerRef = "customerTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ciclocairu.datasource")
    public DataSource ciclocairuDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.palmas.datasource")
    public DataSource palmasDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.megabike.datasource")
    public DataSource megabikeDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource customerDataSource() {
        DataSourceRouter router = new DataSourceRouter();

        final HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>(3);
        map.put(DatabaseEnvironment.CICLOCAIRU, ciclocairuDataSource());
        map.put(DatabaseEnvironment.PALMAS, palmasDataSource());
        map.put(DatabaseEnvironment.MEGABIKE, megabikeDataSource());
        router.setTargetDataSources(map);
        return router;
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.jpa")
    public JpaProperties customerJpaProperties() {
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customerEntityManager(
        final JpaProperties customerJpaProperties) {

        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder =
            createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(customerJpaProperties);

        return builder.dataSource(customerDataSource()).packages(Users.class)
            .persistenceUnit("customerEntityManager").build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager customerTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("customerEntityManager") final EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    private JpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter(
            JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
            AbstractJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            adapter.setShowSql(jpaProperties.isShowSql());
            adapter.setDatabase(jpaProperties.getDatabase());
            adapter.setDatabasePlatform(jpaProperties.getDatabasePlatform());
            //adapter.setGenerateDdl(jpaProperties.isGenerateDdl());
            return adapter;
        }

    private EntityManagerFactoryBuilder createEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(
            JpaProperties customerJpaProperties) {
            JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter =
                createJpaVendorAdapter(customerJpaProperties);
            return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter,
                customerJpaProperties.getProperties(), this.persistenceUnitManager);
        }







}
```

--

```
public class DataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

        if(DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment() == null)
            DatabaseContextHolder.set(DatabaseEnvironment.CICLOCAIRU);

        return DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment();
    }
}
```

--

```
public class EnvironmentAwareCacheKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {

        String key = DatabaseContextHolder.getEnvironment().name() + "-" + (
            method == null ? "" : method.getName() + "-") + StringUtils
            .collectionToDelimitedString(Arrays.asList(params), "-");

        return key;
    }

}
```

I set datasource using 
DatabaseContextHolder.set(DatabaseEnvironment.CICLOCAIRU);

Go to problem:

For example, two users in diferents datasources: 1 and 2

if one user using datasource 1, and send a request, 
The other user that using datasource 2,
yours next request , instead of datasource 2, this get datasource 1. I think that this   `ThreadLocal<DatabaseEnvironment> CONTEXT =
        new ThreadLocal<>();` was exclusive for request, But this does not seem to be so.

Iam sorry if this not be clear.

In realy, i need that DataSurceRouter were exclusive for each request, and an request not intefer in another.

I wrong about i think of DatasourceRouter or my code is bad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably occurs because of server thread pool: you have a given number of threads, and each request is served rolling among them.

When the server recycles a thread, the thread local variable has that value already set from the previous cycle, so you need to flush that value after each request, leaving the thread in a clean state.

Comment: thanks, i implemented one filter in request for clear and set a new datasource and solved this.